# JQuery: combine click / trigger elements for more efficiently written code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, triggers, click

I am trying to figure out a more efficient way to write my code which works but it seems inefficient. Essentially I have a series of Id elements in a nav that trigger a click function on various ids elsewhere on the page. I tried combining my elements but that does not seem to work:

```
$("#red, #green, #blue").bind("click", (function () {

$("#section-red, #section-green, #section-blue").trigger("click");

    alert("#section-red (Red heading) has been triggered!");
    alert("#section-green (Green heading) has been triggered!");
    alert("#section-blue (Blue heading) has been triggered!");

}));
```

... but this just seems to trigger everything.

I can do this below but for lots of ids, it will be a monster to maintain and update. Not sure if there is a better way.

```
 $("#red").bind("click", (function () {
            $("#section-red").trigger("click");
            alert("#section-red (Red heading) has been triggered!");
          }));

   $("#green").bind("click", (function () {
            $("#section-green").trigger("click");
            alert("#section-green (Green heading) has been triggered!");
          }));
// etc...
```

**[I have a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/6aT64/)** that I have been playing with but still no joy.  Essentially a click on the top nav trigger a simulated click on an H2 heading which works but it's just the code efficiency at this point.

Comment: I am confused, what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm trying to combine elements so that my code is more efficiently written instead of having to split it all out like in my fiddle.

Comment: Your second snippet seems straight-forward enough to me. Elegance is nice, but I wouldn't get hung up on it if you already have something simple that works.

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you want the one click to trigger another click? I'm just trying to think of what you can do with that triggered click that you can't do with the original click. Because it could save a lot of efficiency to just use one.

Comment: @KyleWeller -I want to have a nav bar at the top of my page to trigger accordion elements so that a user does not actually have to go and click each H2 accordion item. I think it's a nice UX enhancement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add data attributes to your nav elements like:

```
<ul>
    <li id="red" data-trigger-id="#section-red">Section Red</li>
    <li id="green" data-trigger-id="#section-green">Section Green</li>
    <li id="blue" data-trigger-id="#section-blue">Section Blue</li>
</ul>
```

then in jQuery:

```
$("#red, #green, #blue").bind("click", (function () {
    var triggerID = $(this).data("trigger-id");
    $(triggerID).trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: Using this approach you would end up with 6 event handlers assuming only 3 headers.  Event delegation can limit it to two, no matter how many headers there are.

Answer (score 1):

Using event delegation you only need to register two event handlers.

```
$("ul").delegate("li", "click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
   $("#section-"+id).trigger("click");
});

$(document).delegate("h2", "click", function() {
   console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**EDIT**

You could make it more efficient by caching the element lookups

```
var h2 = [];
h2['red'] = $("#section-red");
h2['blue'] = $("#section-blue");
h2['green'] = $("#section-green");
```

Inside the `ul` delegate `click` handler

```
h2[id].trigger('click');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyVeA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this. This works for all browsers(including IE ;-) )

```
document.onclick = function(event){
    event = event || window.event; //IE does not pass Object of event.
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;    

    switch(target.id){
        case "header-red":
        case "red-section":
            redClicked();
            break;
        case "header-green":
        case "green-section":
            greenClicked();
            break;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would create a class for the `ul` - *in this example, I called it "sections"*:

```
<ul class="sections">
    <li id="red">Section Red</li>
    <li id="green">Section Green</li>
    <li id="blue">Section Blue</li>
</ul>
```

Next, bind a click even to `$('.sections>li')`, get the index, and apply it to the relative div.

```
$(".sections>li").click(function () {
   var index=$(this).index();
   $('.faqfield-question.accordion').eq(index).click();
});
```

That's all there is to it!

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/6aT64/43/

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: This would couple event handling to the layout, i.e. things would have to be in the same order in the nav and in `.faqfield-question.accordion`

Comment: @Floremin We are not talking about a dynamic layout here...This is the layout provided by the OP.  It answers the question. Also if the nav is tied to the accordion element (which the OP said), when would the order ever change? Please read what the OP is looking for before downvoting.

Comment: Initially, it might not matter. I agree, it does not make sense to have them in a different orders. But, in case something needs to be added, say in position 2, or order in the nav changes due to a change in UI requirements, then the change would have to be done in two places, instead of just updating the nav. Having the two decoupled would prevent a potential bug.